# How to convert curl post data to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, curl, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsmutableurlrequest

Hi i want to send a post request to a server with api_key and version
In curl i am able to send via the command

curl -X POST -F "images_file=@fruitbowl.jpg" "https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/visual-recognition/api/v3/classify?api_key=fc1isndcb9fb837d139b11644ksks8cf3d66e175&version=2016-05-20"

When i try to do it in Objective C using the code

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

[request addValue:@"fc1isndcb9fb837d139b11644ksks8cf3d66e175" forHTTPHeaderField:@"api_key"];
[request addValue:@"2016-05-20" forHTTPHeaderField:@"version"];
[request setHTTPBody:strData];

NSError *error = nil;
NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
```

It shows api_key is invalid.
Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: If I click that link, I get the same `invalid-api-key` error.

Comment: Yeh actually i put wrong key on purpose for this question so no one can use that exact link except me. But the key is valid in my actual code

Comment: The `api_key` and the `version` are in the URL, not in the header.

Answer (score 0):

In your `curl` example, the `api_key` and `version` are put in the url path. In your objc example code, you put them in the `header` field, they are not the same.

To achieve the same result, you should merge the two parameters into the `NSURL` entity.